# Is it still possible to register my FB application to use Facebook REST API that is marked as deprecated?

Tags: facebook, rest

Is it possible to register my FB application to use Facebook REST API?

Or is it possible to authenticate in facebook mobile app with no redirection?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to register an app with a particular API - just go ahead and use it, the instructions are all there. However, Facebook *recommends* that you do not use the REST API as it is no longer being supported or updated. Use the Graph API and/or FQL - these are under active development and they're what most of the development community use.

Regarding the mobile app issue, could you give a little more detail? The OS and SDK you're using, for example?

Comment: Unfortunately my new application that uses Graph API successfully is unable to use REST API with the same APIKEY and APISecret. The response I get is:  <error_code>3</error_code>
  <error_msg>Application does not have the capability to make this API call.</error_msg>

Comment: What request are you posting?

Comment: My mobile application is stored entirely on mobile device that only. So I do not want to create a web page just to redirect a user after logging in. And this is required in case of Graph API

Comment: Firstly, I meant, which data are you trying to access with the Graph API? Secondly, which type of mobile device are you using - iOS/Android?

Comment: https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php and in POST method filed I'm performing auth.login request

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear - what I'm trying to find out is, what would be the equivalent request on the Graph API, that you're currently making with REST?

Comment: If you could maybe suggest a way to authorize in Facebook to get access_token with no need for redirect to a web site it would be great. I found out that this in fact is possible with deprecated REST API, but I cannot register new app to use it :(